Interface error when trying to connect database in python using pyodbc
I've been trying to connect Python to an Access database using pyodbc, but I keep getting this error: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
1.Installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 (32-bit), as my MS Office applications are 32-bit.

Ensured the driver in the connection string is {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}.

Ran pyodbc.drivers() to confirm the driver installation.

Attempted switching to 32-bit Python to match the driver architecture.

Restarted my computer to ensure any changes take effec
t.
My python version is 64 bit and also my OS is 64 bit



So all your trials resulted in same error? #4 should have resolved the issue. Did you run pyodbc on a 32-bit Python? Also, please post attempted code block so we can see setup and connection string.
